# 3DCart: possible to access product fields from print_invoice file

Tags: jquery, html, shopping-cart

For some reason, 3DCart does not have a unit of measure field in their product data file. But, I need to put a UOM on invoices. There are plenty of spare fields in the product data file. I just imported the UOM data in to "extra_field_13".

Unfortunately, while I can reference many product fields, that particular field doesn't seem to be accessible. So, while the following brings in data from [fields]:

```
<!--START: items-->
<div class="row">

<div class="invoice-id">[mfgid]</div>
<div class="invoice-items">[itemname]</div>
<div class="invoice-price">[unitprice]</div>
<div class="invoice-qty">[numitems]</div>
<div class="invoice-total">[subtotal]</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!--END: items-->
```

adding a line like:

```
 <div class="invoice-id">[extra_field_13]</div>
```

does not.

Now, 3DCart has a reference here: https://core.3dcart.com/invoice_print-html showing all of the available fields (even though [mfgid] is not on the list, I can still reference it. So, while I had a small sliver of hope extra_field_13 might be accessible, it does not appear to be.

So, my question. Is it possible to write a jquery statement that might pass extra_field_13 to print_invoice.html? I'm not a programmer. But, if this is something possible, I might jump down that rabbit hole. I'm open to any other ideas. I'm hoping some others are familiar enough with 3DCart to know what might be possible, as it seems I'm at a dead end just calling the available fields.

Answer (score 0):

after some more tinkering, I learned that extra_field_[1-10] are accessible. For some reason only extra_field_[11-13] are not.

Luckily we are not using that many extra fields. I just commented out extra_field_10 from displaying on the listing_[x].html file and it pulls just fine to print_invoice.html.